# SSRS - how can my appointment report link to CRM?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, crm

I created report in Visual Studio 2008 to highlight appointments which goes out by email. Now that report goes out, how can I make it so that when user gets the email they can click on any appointment and it will open in CRM?

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible if you have an ability in a web browser to link it with a URL.

For instance you can make the textbox that has your appointment number have an action in the text box properties.  You set the action of the text box to Go To URL.  In the Select URL you would click the expression box and if you have a standard URL like:

```
="http://www.StackOverflow.com/" & Fields!AppointmentNumber.Value
```

it will then allow you to click on the text box and it will open up a browser with that hyperlink.[image: Action Text Box Properties]

There may be another way if you have it built into a Win Forms application rather than the report manager but I am unsure of what that is that can be referenced from a report.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I am little unclear, do I do this for all appointments? or the link will be for all appointments? Where would I be able to get the actual link to use?

Comment: If you have the URL, this needs only be setup once on the Appointment ID field in the text box.  As for the URL, that depends upon how your CRM system is setup.  If you have a web browser page then you should be able to. But if it is a program that is not accessible through the web, it won't allow you to.